# Replace decimal point in input field

Tags: php, jquery

[view pricing table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiTjq.png)

I have a form in which the user can make a selection for buying stamps in various quantities. The form needs to process in cents (to conform with the fingerprint validation) but i need the values to display in dollars and cents as it is visible to the user at all times.

So i need to strip the decimal point from the value of the `$str_rep_amount` variable to form a valid fingerprint.

```
<script>
      $(".stamps_qty").change(function(){
          $.post( "fingerprint.php", $( "#target" ).serialize() ).done( function(data){

              //data = fingerprint
              $('input[name="fingerprint"]').val(data);

          });
      })

      </script>
```

fingerprint.php

```
        $merchant_id= $_POST["merchant_id"];
          $transaction_password= 'abc123';
          $txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
          $ref = $_POST['primary_ref'];
          $amount = $_POST['amount'];
          $str_rep_amount = str_replace( '.', '', $amount ); 
          $time = $_POST["fp_timestamp"];


      $fingerprint =  $merchant_id . '|' . $transaction_password . '|' . $txn_type . '|' . $ref . '|' . $str_rep_amount. '|' . $time;

  //hash the concat stringe with sha1 
  $hash_fp = hash('sha1', $fingerprint);
```

The form data is posted to the server and comes back as the hashed fingerprint so its hard to see what is happening with the `$str_rep_amount` variable.

1.How strip the decimal from `$str_rep_amount`?

2.How can i dump out the contents of `$str_rep_amount` when the data is sent back?

Comment: `die()` may help. It will print anything you pass in and stop the script from executing further.

Comment: Will the value of `$amount` always be in dollars? If yes then you should convert the value of $amount to cents by multiplying with 100 instead of `str_replace( '.', '', $amount ); `

Comment: yes, BCoder is right. As for dumping this on UI, send back the string $fingerprint, without hashing it. And this will then be displayed in the textbox where you will see the data and then can see and debug it there. Once your debugging is done, you can change it back to whatever you need for production version

Comment: Multiply by 100 was a good way to kill off the decimal point.